# Swift dictionary doesn't want to populate from C Callback function

Tags: ios, swift, callback, unsafe-pointers, cgpdf

I'm writing a PDF Parser in Swift and I've reached the point where I get all the font data with a callback function (CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction), the getFont function is supposed to populate the fonts dictionary in the PDFFontCollection class.
Inside the "getFont" callback function the collection variable is correctly populated - however when the callback is finished the fonts dictionary has still 0 entrys.

```
class PDFFontCollection{
var fonts: [AnyHashable:Any]!

init(page: CGPDFPage){
    fonts = [AnyHashable:Any]()

    let fontsdict = self.findFontDictionary(page: page)

    if(fontsdict != nil){
        CGPDFDictionaryApplyFunction(fontsdict!, self.getFont , &self.fonts)
    }
}




private var getFont: CGPDFDictionaryApplierFunction = { (key, object, info) in
    var collection = info?.assumingMemoryBound(to: [AnyHashable: Any].self).pointee

    var name = String(cString: key, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)

    var dict: CGPDFDictionaryRef?
    if (CGPDFObjectGetValue(object, .dictionary, &dict)){
        var font = PDFFont.pdfFont(withFontDictionary: dict!)
        collection?.updateValue(font!, forKey: name!)
    }


}
```

Comment: Been sitting on this for 3 hours now... Still haven't figured what's wrong

Comment: Have you ever heard that Swift `Dictionary` is a value type?

Comment: Yes but doesn't the & specify that I'm passing it by reference?

Comment: Even if accessed through pointers, value type works as value type. Assume you are passing an `Int` pointer to the callback, do you think the original `Int` value would be modified without writing back to the pointer?

Comment: The simple fix is probably using NSDictionary when interacting with C

Answer (score 0):

For whoever may be interested, PeejWeej is right. You need to declare `fonts` as an `NSMutableDictionary` in order to be able to populate it, since `[AnyHashable:Any]` is always passed by reference.